# My Angular view is not updated with data form server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using Angularjs and i make a call form server to retrieve data. Data are successfully retrieved but my view is not updated. I don't understand why. Here are the code i use.

Angularjs and html code :

```
<div class="row custom-margin" ng-controller="ListCtlr" ng-init="initData()">
     <form class="form-inline" role="form" id="formId" name="formId">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="searchInput">Data to search</label>
        <input ng-model="searchInput" placeholder="Enter term to search">
      </div>
      <button type="submitSearch" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="search()">Go</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr class="info">
                <th colspan="4" class="centertext">Name</th>
                <th colspan="3" class="centertext">Age</th>
           </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
           <td>{{person.name}}</td>
           <td>{{person.age}}</td>
           </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Controller code :

```
function ListCtlr($scope, $http, $location,$filter) {

    $scope.formId = {searchInput: ''};

    $scope.search = function () {
        var url='server/search/'+this.searchInput;

        $http.get(url)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.persons = data;

            })
            .error(function(data){
                $scope.error = data;
            });

    };                

}
```

When i inspect the data retrieved form server i get the following JSON data :

```
[{"name":"John","age":12},{"name":"Mary","age":25},{"name":"Garry","age":28}]
```

What's missing please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your ListCtlr controller is placed on a div that does not contain your ng-repeat.

To solve this, create an outer div, put the ng-controller on that div:

```
<div ng-controller="ListCtlr">

   ... (place contents of your html here) ...

</div>
```

This ensures that ListCtlr's scope includes the ng-repeat.

Note: Be sure to remove the ng-controller="ListCtlr" defined in your inner div.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
    <tr ng:repeat="person in persons">
       <td>{{person.name}}</td>
       <td>{{person.age}}</td>
    </tr>
```

to

```
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
       <td>{{person.name}}</td>
       <td>{{person.age}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I add your correction but and thank you. It was not the unique problem. So i still lokk for the solution